# How to open maps from app and drop an arbitrary pin

Tags: xcode, maps, ios6, url-scheme

I've read several questions about this, but no answer seems to fit. If I want to open maps from my app, with an arbitrary location defined by coordinates and an arbitrary name, to use as a title in a pin dropped in that location, how can I do it? With iOS5 I used the openURL with an url scheme built this way:

`maps:q=Arbitrary+name@45.000,45.000`

This doesn't work anymore (thus all the apps to be updated!), and I don't seem to find a way to achieve the same behaviour: the name I provide is always used as a search parameter, and if nothing is found the pin won't be dropped. On the other side, any found result seems to override coordinates, so several pin are dropped in another part of the globe.
I am trying even formats such:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?sll=45.000,45.000&q=Arbitrary+name
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by the following way:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coOrdinates = //
  MKPlacemark *location = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coOrdinates addressDictionary:nil];
  MKMapItem *pinItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endLocation];
  pinItem.name =@"Location";
  NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [pinItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
  [location release];
  [launchOptions release];
  [pinItem release];
```